# Frequency to musical note in Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I created audiocontext and connected my microphone to analyser:

```
context = new AudioContext();
microphone = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
analyser = context.createAnalyser();
analyser.fftSize = 2048;
microphone.connect(analyser);
```

Then I got some arrays with frequencies:

```
fFrequencyData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fFrequencyData);
```

I want to play some musical notes before microphone and then show what note is it.
How I can get frequency of musical note?
For example, A1 = 440.00 Hz, F#3 = 1480.00 Hz.

Thank you!

Comment: FFT isn't enough for this, but it's a step in the right direction.  Here's some code showing how to do it in Coffeescript:  https://github.com/phenomnomnominal/tuner.coffee

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per Brad's comment - you probably don't want to use Realtime Analyser for this.  You can also check out https://github.com/cwilso/PitchDetect - for the precise question you asked, the "noteFromPitch" method, around line 194 of https://github.com/cwilso/PitchDetect/blob/master/js/pitchdetect.js, will do this.

Comment: I know how to get note from frequency, but i don't know how i can get the exact value of the frequency. 440 hz or 1480 hz and other.

Comment: You mean you don't know how to get the exact value of the frequency represented in a bucket in the getByteFrequencyData array?

Comment: Ah.  Well, the centers of the buckets are spread linearly across the range of 0 to the Nyquist frequency of the context; aka one half of the audioContext.sampleRate.  So divide the sample rate by two, then divide that by the size of the array, and that's the "width" of each bucket in Hertz.